# How to add data in firebase database single key multiple values

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I am making a stock management application in which database contains several values like:

- Brand Name
- Product Name
- Design No
- Price

So I want to add products to firebase database in manner in which if brand can contain multiple products in a single node, but product description and price may differ. So can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Without seeing that, it'll be hard to help you better than the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database)] or [codelabs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/#codelabs) do.

Comment: I have tried but not worked

Comment: database.getreference().child().child().setvalue()

Comment: Please click the `edit link under your question to add the additional information. I highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) at this point, as following the guidance in there maximizes the chances that someone can help.